# Braintree Core "Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the store owner." after 2.4.2 upgrade

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, paypal, braintree

After a successful upgrade to magento 2.4.2 from 2.3.3, the gene/braintree module was deleted and replaced with Braintree Core, and I noticed my old settings were retained. I cannot get checkout to initiate, when I click on Paypal or Credit Card (braintree payment options) I get "Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the store owner.". I have created new API keys and verified that my merchant ID is entered correctly, nothing seems amiss in settings. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases depends on a given issue. First do check the cache

Open the site different browser private mode.
or
Open browser with disable cache **Inspect -> Network -> tick a "Disable a cache"**

If any browser Paypal or Braintree show without error. It may browser cache issue

You should disable the any cache like cloudflare or varnish.